# Mount volume to store rancher config

Tags: rancher, rancheros

I started to use RancherOS with rancher 2.*

I was wondering which volume should I mount to keep the config after a hard reboot.

Here is the command I'm using to launch rancher.

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped --name="rancher" -p 8080:80 -p 8443:443 -v /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql  -v /home/rancher/ca.crt:/var/lib/rancher/etc/ssl/ca.crt -v /data:/var/lib/rancher rancher/rancher:latest
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just `-v /data:/var/lib/rancher` is enough.

Also, there is no need for `-v /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`.